# PayPal cart upload goes to white page

Tags: php, paypal

I'm currently trying to integrate a PayPal checkout button to a site but I'm not having much success.
Basically the user can add product numbers and quantities to their cart which is stored on the server. They can then go to a 'view cart' page which will show them the products in their cart. From there they should be able to click a button to transfer all the relevant information to PayPal so they can checkout with PayPal but the button I have generated just goes to a white page (on PayPal's end `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`).

Here is the code for generating the button:

```
$sendPayData = array(
    "METHOD" => "BMCreateButton",
    "USER" => "****",
    "PWD" => "****",
    "SIGNATURE" => "****",
    "BUTTONCODE" => "CLEARTEXT", //Just while debugging
    "BUTTONTYPE" => "BUYNOW",
    "BUTTONCOUNTRY" => "GB",
    "BUTTONIMAGE" => "reg",
    "VERSION" => "65.1"
);

$productInfo = array();

$connection = new mysqli(constant("PERCH_DB_SERVER"),constant("PERCH_DB_USERNAME"),constant("PERCH_DB_PASSWORD"),constant("PERCH_DB_DATABASE"));
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM perch2_shop_products WHERE productCode IN ("'.implode('","',array_keys($_SESSION["cartProducts"])).'")';
if($connection->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed: ".$connection->connect_error);
}

$result = $connection->query($sql);
$total = 0;

if($result->num_rows>0){
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+1)] = 'item_name_'.($i+1).'='.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '',$row["productTitle"]);
        $sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+2)] = 'quantity_'.($i+1).'='.$_SESSION["cartProducts"][$row["productCode"]];
        $sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+3)] = 'amount_'.($i+1).'='.$row["productPrice"];
        $total += $row["productPrice"];
        $i++;
    }
}
$i--;

$sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+4)] = "cmd=_cart";
$sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+5)] = "upload=1";
$sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+6)] = "currency_code=GBP";
$sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+7)] = "business=****";
$sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+8)] = "no_shipping=1";
$sendPayData["L_BUTTONVAR".((3*$i)+9)] = "no_note=1";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?'.http_build_query($sendPayData));
$nvpPayReturn = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

parse_str($nvpPayReturn, $returnArray);

echo $returnArray["WEBSITECODE"];
```

To make things simpler here are the variables that are being sent to paypal (Without the spacing):

```
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?
METHOD=BMCreateButton&
USER=****&
PWD=****&
SIGNATURE=****&
BUTTONCODE=CLEARTEXT&
BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&
BUTTONCOUNTRY=GB&
BUTTONIMAGE=reg&
VERSION=65.1&
L_BUTTONVAR1=item_name_1%3DName1&
L_BUTTONVAR2=quantity_1%3D1&
L_BUTTONVAR3=amount_1%3D6.85&
L_BUTTONVAR4=item_name_2%3DName2&
L_BUTTONVAR5=quantity_2%3D1&
L_BUTTONVAR6=amount_2%3D5.99&
L_BUTTONVAR7=item_name_3%3DName3&
L_BUTTONVAR8=quantity_3%3D1&
L_BUTTONVAR9=amount_3%3D12.85&
L_BUTTONVAR10=cmd%3D_cart&
L_BUTTONVAR11=upload%3D1&
L_BUTTONVAR12=currency_code%3DGBP&
L_BUTTONVAR13=business%3D****&
L_BUTTONVAR14=no_shipping%3D1&
L_BUTTONVAR15=no_note%3D1
```

### UPDATE 1

Turns out paypal wasn't applying the cmd variable and cmd was still:

`<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">`

Instead of:

`<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">`

I'll update if I find out the cause.

As is have said previously this seems to be a problem with PayPal not my php as the white screen was when I transferred to the PayPal website.

### UPDATE 2

It seems that if you set the button type to `cart` instead of `buynow` then it will set `cmd` to `_cart` but will only generate a button if you have `item_name`, `quantity` ect instead of `item_name_1`, `quantity_1` ect. If you do this, however, it will say your cart is empty when you click through to PayPal.
If I manually change the item variables to have `_1` at the then the button will work as intended, displaying the PayPal login page with all the items listed in the order.

**Is there something wrong with PayPals button generator?**

### UPDATE 3

The reason it goes to a white screen is because if you define the `cmd` variable it will just add another one instead of overwriting the old one. Paypal then doesn't know what to do since there are 2 of them.

It doesn't seem there is a way to create an upload cart button unless you make it manually with html, which can be tampered with.

### UPDATE 4

If you change `buynow` to `cart` and delete the `<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">` from the button then it works. For some reason using the `upload=1` variable doesn't override the `add=1` function of the `cart` button and causes your basket to show as empty.

But even though this works in the html version I need to be able to use an encrypted button so I still don't know what to do other than group the order into one item then use the `custom` variable to send the order details through to the IPN.

Comment: White page could mean possible syntax errors. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I have error reporting on, but I should have been clearer. The white page is on PayPal's end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: @D.Hodge are you trying setting enabled the sandbox in paypal? By this mode you enter in testing mode and you can find better the problem

Comment: I didn't really need to use sandbox since I don't need to process payments I just need to get to the cart overview and log in screen, which is just displaying as white.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I am also having similar problems, and need to support encrypted buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this hasn't been answered yet I thought I may as well answer it for others who are in the same boat as I was.

Although this isn't really an answer to whether or not you can achieve what I was trying to achieve using the Paypal button generator, I ended up using the express checkout API instead (Which was what Paypal support suggested instead of the button generator after a few of their suggestions didn't work).

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/

This API appears to have changed slightly since I last used it and there may be a better way now.